# TSQL: Prevent trigger suppressing error but rolling back transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql

I am running into a problem where a part of one of my triggers is failing. This failure is causing the transaction that wraps the trigger to rollback. The problem comes in that it is not raising an error to the invoke point of the command. It is acting like there was no error within the transaction and the only way it is caught is that the data that should have been changed isn't. 
In my example what happens is there are many changes in the transaction. The error occurs in the trigger. everything is rolled back, however, the caller of the command doesn't see a SQL Exception. The caller is never notified that there was an issue.

Is there any way to instruct TSQL to throw the exception in a way that it will report an error to the invoke point of the command?

```
    CREATE TABLE Archive (
        aColumn INT NOT NULL
    )


    CREATE TABLE Source (
        aColumn INT NULL
    )
   --
    CREATE TRIGGER Archive_Trigger ON Source
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Archive
        SELECT DELETED.aColumn
        FROM DELETED
    END

   -- Other attempts
    CREATE TRIGGER Archive_Trigger ON Source
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO Archive
            SELECT DELETED.aColumn
            FROM DELETED
       END TRY
       BEGIN CATCH
            SET XACT_ABORT ON;
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) ;
            SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
            RAISERROR('Error %s occurred in Archive Trigger', 16, 1, @ErrorMessage) ;
       END CATCH
    END
```

This is a really naive version of what the trigger is doing. The problem isn't happening on a production system. When it is happening is in a development environment. When the /Source/ table changes the /Archive/ table must also change. From time to time the archive is forgotten and that is when the error occurs. For example if aColumn was not null in archive and null in Source. This instance would cause the problem.

After having a row in the table with a null aColumn if I execute the following code. The result I expect is to get an exception. I don't.

```
DataSource source;
Connection connection = source.getConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Source SET aColumn = NULL");
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code

Comment: @TheGameiswar I have added some code but I don't know that it will help much. There isn't much in the way of code for the problem.

Comment: You could eliminate the error by explicitly naming the columns on your insert. This should be done as a general way anyway to avoid this exact scenario. Of course if a column is removed this is still an issue.

Comment: Can't we use isnull to rectify the error

Comment: That would fix the error in this case. The problem isn't the particular error. The problem is the skew in the tables. The /Source/ gets changed and the /Archive/ is forgotten. This cause the error which rolls back but don't raise the error.

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON` will cause the transaction to be terminated and SQL to raise an error back to the client application.

Comment: I have tried SET XACT_ABORT ON as well. Added to the example. It still doesn't raise the error to the client.

Comment: RAISERROR does not honor `SET XACT_ABORT ON`.  Replied with more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RAISERROR` statement is not a severe error that halts processing.  In fact, [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792(v=sql.110).aspx):

> The THROW statement honors SET XACT_ABORT. RAISERROR does not. New
>   applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

You can verify this behavior by running the following SQL:

```
set xact_abort on
begin tran
raiserror('error 1', 16, 1, null)
raiserror('error 2', 16, 1, null)
```

The output will be:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
error 1
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
error 2
```

Any attempt to raise a severe error will fail unless you are a sysadmin:

> Msg 2754, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Error severity levels greater than
>   18 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin role, using the
>   WITH LOG option.

I do think you should use SET XACT_ABORT ON, but either:

1) Do a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` during the actual `INSERT`.  This will cause the original error to terminate the connection.

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Archive_Trigger ON Source
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    INSERT INTO Archive
    SELECT DELETED.aColumn
    FROM DELETED
END
```

2) Alternatively, you could cause a more severe error in the `BEGIN CATCH` statement.  For example, cause a divide by 0 error with a `SELECT 1/0`.  The client will have to ignore the divide by zero error to get the error message you raised.

Note that [the original SET XACT_ABORT setting will be restored after leaving the trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356(v=sql.110).aspx) (search for "trigger").

When the trigger does cause an error that cancels the trigger, SQL Server will raise the error 3609 to the client with the text:

> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

We had this specific issue happen in our application.  A transaction was killed inside a trigger.  The client application did not receive the error and continued onward outside of a transaction.  Very bad things happened at this point.

We solved this by having our data access object (DAO) detect when the current database connection is closed, broken, or the transaction is null.  In this case, if a SQL error was returned in a SqlException.Errors with a number of 3609, the DAO throws a specific "the transaction ended in the trigger" exception.

Answer (score 1):

Some exceptions have [severity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) that is not enough to break execution of current batch. It just goes on and performs subsequent statements. If I'm not mistaken, constraint violation is not a batch-breaking error for example.

To ensure whole batch breaks on noticeable error you may set [XACT_ABORT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792(v=sql.120).aspx) option to `ON` which also will rollback *entire transaction* if established.

Best way to manage exception is to surround your code with TRY-CATCH block which is [supposed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.120).aspx) to react on all errors with severity higher than info messages and lower than errors breaking connection. After falling into CATCH block (which can not be avoided unless you are intentionally silencing exceptions) you may throw another user-defined exception, rollback and so on, as you know it yourself. TRY-CATCH guaranties that your code will react on exceptions if any.

Enabling `XACT_ABORT` inside of `TRY-CATCH` is not recommended because it's a bit senseless: you are attempting to *control* behavior of your code in case of exception (with try-catch) and at the same time telling to server *"abort'em all!"* (with xact_abort).

Comment: I have updated my example to have the try catch on it.  Even with the try catch and raising the error level to 16 which I believe should be high enough the invoke point still doesn't get notified of the error in the trigger.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx

Comment: Try-catch is supposed to be outside of the trigger surrounding DML statements. And there is no need of xact_abort in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your devs are creating the trigger but inserting into the wrong archive table because they forgot to change the script?

What we do is create all audit triggers using dynamic sql. Our design has the same columns for every audit table (basically a rowid which is the id column of the table, a column name column and an old value column and a new value column. So what we are sending in dynamically is the name of the table we are creating which is based on putting the variable of the tablename you want the trigger for in the variable used in the dynamic sql. Its a little more complicated if you want to make the audit tables match the columns of the table, then you need to grab the column names from the system tables and put in a temp table and join to that in your dynamic sql.

When it is time to create the audit tables and triggers, we run one script that does both and all we have to do is input the name of the database and table we are putting the audit table on.

It takes a while to get this worked out just right, but once you do, creating new auditing is a snap and you never get mistakes like referencing the wrong audit table.

Comment: I do like the idea. However, it doesn't answer the question.