# THROW ERROR Still Executes Query And Inserts Data Into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, throw, raiserror

Basically, I am trying to compare a date the user will enter and if it is greater than todays date (GETDATE()), then it throws the error and doesn't enter the data. The query throws the error but it still enters the data with the result at the bottom.

```
USE EMR
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT DB_ID('CheckDate'))
    DROP TRIGGER CheckDate
    GO

CREATE TRIGGER CheckDate
ON VISIT
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20) = CAST ((SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(20))
    SET @ErrorMessage = 'Date Must Be On Or Before ' + @Date + '';

    DECLARE @CheckDate DATE = (SELECT Date_Of_Service FROM inserted);

    IF CAST((@CheckDate) AS DATE) <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        COMMIT TRAN

    ELSE
        RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 1, 1)
```

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO VISIT (PK_VISIT_ID, Date_Of_Service)
VALUES (02913, '2018-12-03')
```

And get this:

```
Date Must Be On Or Before 2016-02-17
Msg 50000, Level 1, State 1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Why not [`THROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ee677615.aspx) an error instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are raising error with `severity` = 1 which means to server that it's just **info message**.

Check out replies to this post: [TSQL: Prevent trigger suppressing error but rolling back transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35462769/tsql-prevent-trigger-suppressing-error-but-rolling-back-transaction/35465644#35465644)
There is also a link to severity table on msdn.

Comment: I attempted to change it to use severity 16, although it doesn't look like its working.

Comment: ELSE RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1). I believe this is the proper syntax, but it is still inserting the data

Comment: How are you handling exceptions? You have to check for errors outside. By the way trigger is not good place for `COMMIT`. You may put there `ROLLBACK` first, then `raiserror`. So the logic is a bit reversed in current implementation.

Comment: That makes sense. We really only focus on doing ROLLBACK and COMMIT in Functions and Procedures, but when I put the rollback anywhere in there, I get this: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CheckDate, Line 20
Date Must Be On Or Before 2016-02-17
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: Ok, you may continue raising error but you have to handle exception outside. TRY-CATCH (please review link to similar question)

Comment: The best approach ever is to check before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is giving doing insert even after raiserror because trigger for insert runs the trigger after the rows are inserted.You can use check constraint or instead of insert as follows:

```
alter trigger tr2 on bb
instead of insert
as
begin
    begin try
        begin transaction
            if exists(select * from inserted where date1  > getdate())
                    begin
                        raiserror('date greater then today''s date',16,1)
                    end

                else
                    begin
                        insert into bb
                        select * from inserted
                        if @@trancount > 0
                        commit transaction
                    end
    end try

    begin catch
        declare @msg varchar(100) = error_message()
            if @@trancount > 0
                begin
                    raiserror(@msg,16,1)
                    rollback transaction
                end         
    end catch
end
```